# Why are empty bytes returned as a response?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.8, aiohttp

I'm in the process of learning python asynchrony. My problem is that I am trying to get an answer in the form of streaming content, but as I did not try, empty bytes always come. What is the reason? What am I doing wrong?
I chose the Github API as an example.

I use version python 3.8, aiohttp 3.7.4.

Here is my code:
import json
import aiohttp
import asyncio
async def get_response():
url = 'https://api.github.com/events'
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
task1 = asyncio.create_task(make_request(session, url))
result = await asyncio.gather(task1)
return result

```
async def make_request(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        json_resp = await resp.json(loads=json.loads)
        bytes_resp = await resp.content.read(10)
        print(json_resp)
        print(bytes_resp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(get_response())
```

Many thanks.

Getting this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nreBQ.png)

Comment: I had to correct some indentation in your code, but i managed to get a response from 'https://api.github.com/events' of b'[{"id":"17', currently using aiohttp 3.7.4 and python 3.8. do you just get a response of b''?

Comment: Yes. but if I remove json_resp from my code, then everything is ok

Comment: Do you need to add import json to the top? I just ran it and the json_resp printed out the whole response from the url.

Comment: I accidentally forgot to add this to the code used in the question.I'll fix it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't both read the response once as JSON and again as bytes, as it is already consumed at that point. (aiohttp purposely doesn't buffer the response data internally.)

If you need both,

```
bytes_resp = await resp.content.read()
json_resp = json.loads(bytes_resp)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything worked for me. And can I somehow make the most of the possibilities of StreamReader?

Comment: Totally depends on what you want to do. That events JSON endpoint isn't a live stream, if that's what you're going for...

Comment: I would like to be able to iterate asynchronously on the received response.

Comment: Then you'd just need a loop that does smaller reads from the response stream :)